# Как перфекционировать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eсть такая структура страницы

```js
$('#sectione_one').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    $('.aside a').addClass('active');
    console.log('вижу')
  } else {
    $('.aside a').removeClass('active');
    console.log('не вижу')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside">
    <a href="#sectione_one"></a>
    <a href="#sectione_two"></a>
    <a href="#sectione_three"></a>
    <a href="#sectione_four"></a>
    <a href="#sectione_five"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section id="sectione_one"></section>
    <section id="sectione_two"></section>
    <section id="sectione_three"></section>
    <section id="sectione_four"></section>
    <section id="sectione_five"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Навигационое меню `.aside` фиксировано слева.

Надо сделать, что бы при скролле, если видно в поле зрение браузера, соответствующая ссылка `a` получала  класс `active`, где `id` страницы и `href`ссылки совпадают

Так вот скрипт( с использование библиотеки)

Тут когда дохожу до секции `#reviews`, то `a` из `aside` получает класс `active`. Проблема в том, что сейчас получает все ссылки получают класс `active`. Мне же надо добавить класс только ссылке, которая совпадает с `id` секции. 
Так же не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы скрипт работал для всех секций и ссылок меню, а не для каждой в отдельности.

Comment: `$('.aside a[href="#sectione_one"]').toggleClass('active', isInView);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $('section').each(function() {
    $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').removeClass('active');
    if (isVisible($(this), $(window))) {
      $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

function isVisible(row, container) {
  var elementTop = $(row).offset().top,
    elementHeight = $(row).height(),
    containerTop = container.scrollTop(),
    containerHeight = container.height();
  return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0) && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
}
```

```css
.aside {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.aside a {
  display: block
}

.content section {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: right
}

.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside">
    <a href="#sectione_one" class="active">sectione_one</a>
    <a href="#sectione_two">sectione_two</a>
    <a href="#sectione_three">sectione_three</a>
    <a href="#sectione_four">sectione_four</a>
    <a href="#sectione_five">sectione_five</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section id="sectione_one">sectione_one</section>
    <section id="sectione_two">sectione_two</section>
    <section id="sectione_three">sectione_three</section>
    <section id="sectione_four">sectione_four</section>
    <section id="sectione_five">sectione_five</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потенциально, ваш код должен принимать следующий вид:

```
$('.content section').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
     var sId = $(this).attr("id");

     $(".aside a[href='#" + sId + "']").toggleClass('active', isInview);
});
```

Проблема возникнет, когда в экран будет влезать, например, сразу два `section`. В таком случае можно получить, что в меню, активными можно получить сразу два пункта.